# Is there an example of using CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore under Linux?

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

There is a package [CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore/)
There is [an example of its use under Windows](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example.netcore.csproj)

In theory, the package CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore should be different from CefSharp.OffScreen cross-platform, that is, the ability to work under Linux. But judging by the example code of its use, it still depends on Windows.

Can this package CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore work under Linux?
If it can, where can I see an example of its use under Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CefSharp is built with Visual C++ which only runs on Windows.

Comment: You might want to look at puppeteer Sharp as an alternative https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp

Comment: Sorry :( Take cross - platform Chromium and cross - platform .Net Core to make a library only for Windows - is a very strange idea! Only for Windows exist vanilla "WebView 2" around Edge from Microsoft.

Comment: By all means vote on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/netcore-ccli-for-linux-and-macos/873014 asking Microsoft to port visual c++ to linux/mac